# Symfony RestBundle: @View annotation stopped working after v2 upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.4

I think there's a conflict between JMS serializer and FOSRestBundle: I get an empty json object instead of id and accessToken.
Am I missing some v2 documentation?

## config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: false
            json: false
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
```

## Controller

```
class SecurityController extends FOSRestController
{
     *
     * @View(serializerGroups={"login"})
     *
     */
    public function postLoginAction(Request $request)
    {
            // $user = MyOAuthUserResponse extends AbstractUserResponse

           // before upgrade I just use: return $this->view($user);

            $view = $this->view($user);

            $context = new Context();
            $context->addGroup('login');

            $view->setContext($context);

            return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

## Entity

```
/**
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("All")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $accessToken;
```

Comment: No errors / warnings etc? Symfony thinks everything is great?

Comment: No errors: just empty json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It found the issue!

In `vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php:209`

```
$exclusionStrategy = $context->getExclusionStrategy(); // Returns NULL
```

Which seems to work fine (before the upgrade) with:

```
return $this->view($user);
```

But since the upgrade the $exclusionStrategy returns:

```
JMS\Serializer\Exclusion\GroupsExclusionStrategy Object
(
    [groups:JMS\Serializer\Exclusion\GroupsExclusionStrategy:private] => Array
        (
            [login] => 1
        )

    [nestedGroups:JMS\Serializer\Exclusion\GroupsExclusionStrategy:private] =>
```

)

In order to fix that I removed the context code I passed to the view and pass the `view` to the `handleview` like:

```
return $this->handleView($this->view($user));
```

I was mistaken by this [upgrade doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING-2.0.md):

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;

$view = new View();

$context = new Context();
$view->setContext($context);

$context = $view->getContext();
```